# Y = churn.iloc[:, 18].values

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to import my dataset(18 columns counting from 0) i got this error:

> File "C:/Users/ASUS/PycharmProjects/PA/BestAcc.py", line 23, in
>   
>       Y = churn.iloc[:, 18].values   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in
>   **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_tuple(key)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2013, in
>   _getitem_tuple
>       self._has_valid_tuple(tup)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 222, in
>   _has_valid_tuple
>       self._validate_key(k, i)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1957, in
>   _validate_key
>       self._validate_integer(key, axis)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2009, in
>   _validate_integer
>       raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds") IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

churn = pd.read_csv("HR.csv")

#import colums except the first one in the dataset

X = churn.iloc[:, 1:18].values

Y = churn.iloc[:, 18].values
```

Answer (score 0):

`iloc` has been deprecated in later versions of `pandas` - I would suggest using `loc` instead -

```
X = churn.loc[:, churn.columns[1:18]]
Y = churn.loc[:, churn.columns[18]]
```